# Average of 3 numbers using integers

Tags: math, floating-point, integer, average

I would like to compute the average of three numbers, like:

```
d = int(round((a + b + c) / 3.0))
```

Where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are integers.

Is it possible to get the same result using just integers?

I'm interested in this because of performance reasons, I assume doing the math using integers should be faster than using floats.

The example above converts the integers to floats, calculates the result, rounds it and converts back to integer. Is it possible to avoid the int <-> float conversions?

Comment: What is the average of 1,1, 2 ? what integral result do you want?

Comment: are a,b,c integers to start with?

Comment: @Mark: 1, 1, 2 -> 1; 1, 2, 2 -> 2

Comment: Note that on today's PC with the optimized FPUs, the performance difference is going to be negligible - if there still is one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the requirements for  1, 1, 2 -> 1; 1, 2, 2 -> 2  then this can be done using integer division.

Using // for the integer division and n for number of elements.

```
average = ( a+ b + c + .... + n//2 ) // n
```

ie sum up all the values and then add a number to deal with rounding.

As noted in @Henrik's answer this assumes that all numbers are positive.

Comment: Yes, the numbers are positive. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`(a + b + c + 1) / 3`

Explanation: if (a + b + c) % 3 == 1, it's rounded down; if (a + b + c) % 3 == 2, it's rounded up.

At least this should work for `a + b + c >= 0`. You may need to treat negative values separately.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of Mahmoud's answer using only one division:

```
d = (((a+b+c) * 10) + 15) / 30
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as that:

```
d = (((a+b+c) * 10) / 3 + 5) / 10;
```

Comment: What is wrong with this site lately?  Why are all these people acting as judge and jury, deciding what's a comment and what's not, without offering anything of value themselves?

Comment: @duffymo thanks for the up-vote as I cannot believe myself giving the right answer and take down votes! All the other answers are derivative from this answer by multipling with a factor or replace 3 with N for number of elements.

Comment: I still say the entire idea is off base, but that's not a good reason to downvote anyone who's acting in good faith.  It's a poorly conceived question in my view.  I'm sick and tired of these useless commenters.

Comment: -1 because the answer does not explain why or if it works - it does not matter if the response is in good faith - we are aiming to improve the quality of questions and answers here. and my answer is definitely not derived from this.